# How do I show JSON data in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm doing the REST Countries API with color theme switcher project from Frontend Mentor. I'm using React to do this but I'm getting errors in the console. This is the Country Component:

```
import react from "react";
import './contry.styles.css';

export const Country = (props) => (
    <div className="flex-containercountry">
        <div className="flex-itemscountry">
            <img alt="country" src={props.country.flags[0]}></img>
            <h1>{props.country.name}</h1>
            <h3>Population: {props.country.population}</h3>
            <h3>Region: {props.country.region}</h3>
            <h3>Capital: {props.country.capital}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default Country;
```

This is the Country List component:

```
import react from "react";
import './countrylist.styles.css';
import { Country } from "./country.component";

export const CountryList = props => (
    <div className="countrylist">
        {props.country.map(country => (<Country key={props.country.name}/>))}
    </div>
);

export default CountryList;
```

And this is the main App component:

```
import HeaderWithDarkMode from './components/headerwithdarkmode.component';
import SearchBarWithFilter from './components/searchbarwithfilter.component';
import './App.css';
import { Component } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import CountryList from './components/countrylist.component';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      countries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            countries: result.all
          });
        },
        
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, countries } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <HeaderWithDarkMode/>
          <SearchBarWithFilter/>
          <CountryList/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I execute the project with "npm start" the page becomes blank and I got a lot of erros in the console like:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at CountryList (bundle.js:278:27)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:22826:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:25588:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:26787:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:11776:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:11825:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:11885:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:31627:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:30463:16)
    at workLoopSync (bundle.js:30400:9)
react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <CountryList> component:

    at CountryList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278:19)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
countrylist.component.jsx:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at CountryList (bundle.js:278:27)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:22826:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:25588:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:26787:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:11776:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:11825:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:11885:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:31627:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:30463:16)
    at workLoopSync (bundle.js:30400:9)
modalComponent.js:2 Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
    at chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:350577
    at Dc (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:257067)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:274846)
    at Yo (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197386)
    at Nc (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:256528)
    at yc (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:248018)
    at chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197609
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:274846)
    at Yo (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197386)
    at Ko (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197554)
sl @ modalComponent.js:2
modalComponent.js:2 Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
    at chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:350577
    at Dc (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:257067)
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:274846)
    at Yo (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197386)
    at Nc (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:256528)
    at yc (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:248018)
    at chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197609
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:274846)
    at Yo (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197386)
    at Ko (chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js:2:197554)
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/content.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/modalComponent.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fhamhppabjaafimidmelnmpfangjdnhj/analytics.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT ""
```

Does anyone have an ideia of what is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping over a prop called `country`:

```
props.country.map(/.../)
```

But you never supplied any props:

```
<CountryList/>
```

So `props.country` is `undefined`, as the error indicates.  To define it, pass that prop to the component.  For example:

```
<CountryList country={countries} />
```

Comment: I put country={countries} in CountryList component but I'm still getting erros

Comment: @zennarooh: Are you getting *the exact same* error, or a new error?

Comment: I put <CountryList country={countries}/> in App.js. The console is showing this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

Comment: @zennarooh: And what is the value of `countries` when that happens?  The default value for that state property is an empty array.  But then after an AJAX operation you update it here: `countries: result.all`  If I go to that URL manually, I receive an array of objects.  So, when you debug, is `result` an array?  There is no `.all` property on arrays, so `result.all` is `undefined`.  You need to debug and double-check what values you're passing around in your variables.  You *probably* just want to set `state.countries` to `result` itself.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.